# Inserting Colons into a list of Mac Addresses

Tags: replace, scripting, insert

I have over 500 MAC addresses and I'm trying to find a simple way to insert colons between every 2 characters.

Answer (score 7):

You could get notepad++ and do a search and replace with regex like search for (..) and replace with \1:

Comment: Why would '\1-' insert a colon?

Answer (score 6):

It maybe overkill, but I would use Excel.  Paste your MAC addresses into column A and this formula into column B:

```
=LEFT(A1,2)&":"&MID(A1,3,2)&":"&MID(A1,5,2)&":"&MID(A1,7,2)&":"&MID(A1,9,2)&":"&RIGHT(A1,2)
```

Then, you can `copy` column B, and either `paste special...values` into column C or just paste into Notepad.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a sed command such as this:

```
sed 's/\(\w\w\)\(\w\w\)\(\w\w\)\(\w\w\)\(\w\w\)\(\w\w\)/\1:\2:\3:\4:\5:\6/g' filename
```

This will just pull out 12 characters in groups of two, and spit them back out with colons in the middle. You could also try a simpler pattern like s/(\w\w)/\1:/g, though this will leave you with an extra colon at the end of every address.

Comment: Beat me to it!  In re to your last sentance, you could then use another sed command to strip the trailing colon, and it might still be shorter.

Comment: Not all versions of 'sed' support '\w' to mean a word-character.  Greater precision in the match ('[0-9a-fA-F]') would make the iterative solution preferable.

Comment: I'd personally probably do it in Perl, but I have to upvote the decently simple Regex way of doing it.
perl -e "while (<>) {$_ =~ s/(\w{2})/$1:/g; s/:$/$/;}"
.. I think that one would do it.

Answer (score 2):

=CONCATENATE(MID(A2;1;2);":";MID(A2;3;2);":";MID(A2;5;2);":";MID(A2;7;2);":";MID(A2;9;2))

This should help in OpenOffice

=CONCATENATE(MID(A7,1,2),":",MID(A7,3,2),":",MID(A7,5,2),":",MID(A7,7,2),":",MID(A7,9,2),":",MID(A7,11,2))

Here it is in excel, i used your answer above and built off it, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it's a one time thing, why not use emacs with a keyboard macro?

[youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9NYTb3mVCvk)

Answer (score 1):

```html
 Linux, UNIX  - Bash 
Given a address like MACstr="cc0deca96acf"
MACfiexd=$(sed -e 's/.\{2\}/&:/g;s/.$//' <<<$MACstr)
echo "$MACfixed"
cc:0d:ec:a9:6a:cf
```

Answer (score 1):

Matt's solution using Notepad++, but fine-tuned to only change lines that (only) contain a mac address:

FIND: `^(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)$`

REPLACE: `\1:\2:\3:\4:\5:\6`

Answer (score 1):

assuming all MAC's are in a file, one MAC per line:

`sed -i 's/../&:/g;s/:$//' FILE`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick PowerShell example:

```
$macs = Get-Content C:\temp\MAC.txt
$output = foreach ($mac in $macs){
    $mac.insert(2,":").insert(5,":").insert(8,":").insert(11,":").insert(14,":")
}
$output | Out-File c:\temp\newmac.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$macs = Get-Content C:\temp\MAC.txt
$output = foreach ($mac in $macs){
    $mac.insert(2,":").insert(5,":").insert(8,":").insert(11,":").insert(14,":")
}
$output | Out-File c:\temp\newmac.txt
```

Thanks Jonathan Walz!  Worked like a CHARM!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to add MAC address colons to an existing HTML table in vim:

```
:%s/<td> \([0-9a-zA-Z]\{2\}\)\([0-9a-zA-Z]\{2\}\)\([0-9a-zA-Z]\{2\}\)\([0-9a-zA-Z]\{2\}\)\([0-9a-zA-Z]\{2\}\)\([0-9a-zA-Z]\{2\}\) <\/td>/<td> \1:\2:\3:\4:\5:\6 <\/td>/g
```